# bash extract version string & convert to version dot

Tags: linux, string, bash, sh

I want to extract version string (1_4_5) from `my-app-1_4_5.img` and then convert into dot version (1.4.5) without filename. Version string will have three (1_4_5) or four (1_4_5_7) segments.

Have this one liner working `ls my-app-1_4_5.img | cut -d'-' -f 3 | cut -d'.' -f 1 | tr _ .`

Would like to know if there is any better way rather than piping output from `cut`.

Comment: If file names are always something like `file-name-x-1_2_3_4.ext`, then you can simply `echo file-name-x-1_2_3_4.ext | tr _ .`.

Comment: I have updated my Q. Want just  dot version number at the end. No filename.

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and don't use external utilities when the shell has built-in parameter expansion and regex matching.

Comment: Can you clarify whether the version always has three segments? If it hasn't, can it be assumed that there will only be a single sequence of numbers separated by underscore (including possibly a single number) in the filename?

Comment: I would use `ls my-app-1_4_5.img | sed 's/^.*-//;s/\..*$//;s/_/./g'` . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter your solution worked, please add as an answer below.

Comment: With GNU awk: `awk '$1=$1' FPAT='[0-9]+' OFS='.'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove everything but `0` to `9`, `_` and newline and then replace all `_` with `.`:

```
echo "my-app-1_4_5.img" | tr -cd '0-9_\n' | tr '_' '.'
```

Output:

```
1.4.5
```

Comment: This worked for `my-app-1_4_5.img`, `my-app-1_4_5_6.img`, `my-app-1_4_55_6.img`, `my-app-new-1_4_55_6.img`, `my-app-new-6.img`, `my-app-new-55_6.img`

Comment: @roy be aware that this will fail if your files contain numbers that aren't part of the version, for instance `fail2ban-1_4_5.img` would yield 21.4.5 instead of the expected 1.4.5. Not that this make this solution bad, each of the answers here have their limitations

Answer (score 3):

Here's an attempt with parameter expansion. I'm assuming you have a wildcard pattern you want to loop over.

```sh
for file in *-*.img; do
    base=${file%.img}
    ver=${base##*-}
    echo "${ver//_/.}"
done
```

The construct `${var%pattern}` returns the variable `var` with any suffix matching `pattern` trimmed off. Similarly, `${var#pattern}` trims any prefix which matches `pattern`. In both cases, doubling the operator switches to trimming the longest possible match instead of the shortest. (These are POSIX-compatible pattenr expansion, i.e. not strictly Bash only.) The construct `${var/pattern/replacement}` replaces the first match in `var` on `pattern` with `replacement`; doubling the first slash causes every match to be replaced. (This is Bash only.)

Comment: Isn't that almost the same answer as mine? Why duplicate it?

Comment: We answered pretty much at the same time. If you want to copy the explanatory section from here, I'll delete mine.

Comment: Nah... no worries.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with *sed*:

```
sed -E "s/.*([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+).*/\1.\2.\3/" <<< my-app-1_4_5.img
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `-E` rather than `-r` : it works both on modern GNU sed and BSD sed, and is coherent with `grep`'s use of the same flag to switch to the ERE regex flavour

Comment: That will cover only fixed versions with three places. What about something like `1_2` or `1_2_3_4`?

Comment: @accdias OP should clearly clarify this point, because if you want to be as generic as possible you'll have to match single numbers too, which I feel like would yield many false positives

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the version number will always be between the last dash and the file extension, you can use something like this in pure Bash:

```sh
name="file-name-x-1_2_3_4_5.ext"
version=${name##*-}
version=${version%%.ext}
version=${version//_/.}
echo $version
```

The code above will result in:

```
1.2.3.4.5
```

For a complete explanation about the brace expansions used above, please take a look at [Bash Reference Manual: 3.5.1 Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion).

Comment: Linking to the ABS is dubious IMHO. Sometimes it's the only extensive source on a topic but even then I like to put in a caveat. Usually you can find less confused and more concise expositions.

Answer (score 1):

With bash and a regex:

```
echo "my-app-1_4_5.img" | while IFS= read -r line; do [[ "$line" =~ [^0-9]([0-9_]+)[^0-9] ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]//_/.}"; done
```

Output:

```
1.4.5
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly shorter variant

```
name=my-app-1_4_5.img
vers=${name//[!0-9_]}
$ echo ${vers//_/.}
1.4.5
```

Comment: Did you check what your code does when you have something like `name=123-my-app-1_4_5.img`?

Comment: @accdias Obviously my solution doesn't cover this scenario, it's just a quick hack)